# Проблема с привязкой программы по имени компьютера

Tags: c++

Хочу сделать небольшую привязку к существующей программе и чтобы она работала только на моём компьютере.

Я использовал `GetComputerName`.
Принцип такой: Я уже вбил своё имя компьютера в переменную.
Затем при запуске программы вызываю функцию `GetComputerName` и получаю текущее имя компьютера,затем я сравниваю со своей переменной константной где уже вбито имя компьютера и если оно совпадает то программа меня впускает,а если не совпадает(чужой компьютер) то пишет "Доступ закрыт"

К сожалению она на своём же компьютере пишет что доступ закрыт. Возможно я не правильно сделал условный оператор,возможно что-то другое.
Код программы:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

#define MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH 15
#define BUFSIZE 1024

char compname[20] = "Здесь введите имя своего компьютера";
char buffalpha[34] = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя";

void shifr(char buff[100], int x, int k)
{
    cout << "Введете сообщение для шифрования:" << endl;
    cin >> buff;
    for(int i = 0;i<strlen(buff);i++)
    {
        for(int l = 0;l<strlen(buffalpha);l++)
            if(buff[i] == buffalpha[l]) x = l;
        int j;
        j = (x + k) % (strlen(buffalpha));
        buff[i] = buffalpha[j];
    }
    cout << "Зашифрованное сообщение:\n" << endl;
    cout << buff << endl;
}

void deshifr(char buff[100], int i, int y, int k)
{
    cout << "Введите сообщение для дешифрования:" << endl;
    cin >> buff;
    cout << "Дешифрованное собщение: " << endl;
    for(i = 0;i<strlen(buff);i++)
    {
        for(int l = 0;l<strlen(buffalpha);l++)
            if(buff[i] == buffalpha[l]) y = l;
        int j;
        j = ((y + (strlen(buffalpha)) - (k % (strlen(buffalpha))))) % (strlen(buffalpha));
        buff[i] = buffalpha[j];
    }
    cout << buff << endl;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int i = 0, x = 0, y = 0, k = 3, num;
    char buff[100] = "";
    char buffer[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1];
    DWORD size;
    size = sizeof(buffer);
    GetComputerName(buffer, &size);
    if(compname == buffer)
        do
        {
            srand(NULL);
            cout << "Добро пожаловать!";
            cout << "Выберите алгоритм:\n"
                << "1. Шифрование.\n"
                << "2. Дешифрование.\n"
                << "3. Выход.\n";
            cin >> num;
            switch(num)
            {
            case 1:
                shifr(buff, x, k);
                break;
            case 2:
                deshifr(buff, i, y, k);
                break;
            case 3:
                exit(0);
                break;
            }
        } while(num != 0);
    else cout << "Доступ закрыт!" << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста отформатируйте код

Comment: @Cerbo тут одного форматирования мало. Код по большому счету сишный.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В языке C `char *` и `char[]` - очень похожи, при обращении к ним без квадратных скобок, как у вас в `if` они интерпретируются как *адреса* областей памяти, где лежат сами строки. Поэтому сравнение `if (compname==buffer)` сравнивает просто эти 2 числа между собой и они разумеется не равны, потому как указывают на разные области памяти.

Для сравнения строк в `C` используются функции типа `strcmp`:

```
if(strcmp(compname,buffer)==0) ...
```

Фунция strcmp возвращает 0 если строки *равны* или +-N в зависимости от того, какая строка больше

Comment: тогда по возможности нажмите стрелочку вверх у моего ответа и под ним поставьте галочку ;)

Comment: @Mike Массив и указатель - это не одно и то же.

Comment: @Mike, char[] — это не указатель, но он может быть в него конвертирован.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, Вроде поправил ответ. Думаю так будет и не сложно описано, для понимания сути и правильно с точки зрения теории